# Laravel eloquent not retrieving results based on boolean column

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, boolean

I have 33 results on my DB where this boolean field (resolvido) is showing zero, if I run the SQL query it retrieves the results, however in the model the collection always comes empty.

If I change to `Model::where('resolvido',1)->get()`, I do get the correspondent results, however the `Model::where('resolvido',0)->get()` or the `Model::where('resolvido',false)->get()` or even using the query builder and raw sql, the collection never picks up those 33 results where `resolvido = 0`.

I've also tried in Tinker and it always comes up empty.

Migration:

```
        $table->boolean('resolvido')->nullable();
```

On DB comes up as TINYINT

Any tips on what it might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the column called `resolved` or `resolvido` just to make things clear.

Comment: Thank you, I was just giving an example but now have edited the question to reflect the real field name "resolvido"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Naturally, there is [no boolean data type for MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/) but rather uses `TINYINT` (0 or 1) for this.

Laravel's query builder, allows using boolean in the where clause. You might want to try these:

```php
Model::where('resolved', true)->get();
Model::where('resolved', false)->get();
```

Since you've set the `resolved` column in the DB as `nullable`, you might also want to try:

```php
Model::where('resolved', null)->get();
```

If you don't want that behavior use `$table->boolean('resolved')->default(false)` instead

Comment: And sorry the bad formatting, trying the double space but still not doing a new line. Getting used to this. eheh

Comment: Also same behaviour using `TRUE` or `FALSE`, 

`Ocorrencia::where('resolvido', true)->get()` returns a lot of data, 

`Ocorrencia::where('resolvido', false)->get()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Model::where('resolved', null)->get()
```

or

```
Model::where('resolved', '')->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

In migration, it is necessary to add the default value for it to work properly. Otherwise, it will always be filled by **NULL**.

Like:

```
$table->boolean('resolvido')->default(0);
```

Knowing that **1** or **0** is True or False. You will be able to refer to these values ​​only by **TRUE** or **FALSE**. If you don't enter anything in the 'resolvido' field when insert data, it will always be registered as **FALSE (0)** in this case.